# Rails 4 - Heroku logs -how to make sense of an error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, associations

I'm trying to push some code to heroku.

I get this error message from the heroku logs. I can't make any sense of it.

so far as I can decipher, it's something to to with my user and roles models, which are:

User

```
rolify
   attr_accessor :current_role


has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, join_table: "users_roles"
```

Role

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base



  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: "users_roles"
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

  scopify



end
```

User_Roles join table has:

```
create_table "users_roles", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end

  add_index "users_roles", ["user_id", "role_id"], name: "index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id", using: :btree
```

Can anyone understand what this error message means?

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1694: warning: already initialized constant User::HABTM_Roles
2016-04-22T03:11:57.250562+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1694: warning: previous definition of HABTM_Roles was here
2016-04-22T03:11:58.690994+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ! Unable to load application: ArgumentError: Unknown key: :polymorphic. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type
2016-04-22T03:11:58.691033+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:75:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :polymorphic. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type (ArgumentError)
```

I just found the resource below describing how 'rolify' incorporates the HABTM relationship on the user model so it doesnt need to be listed separately as an association, but I still get this error:

```
Preloading application
2016-04-22T04:09:58.023038+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ! Unable to load application: ArgumentError: Unknown key: :polymorphic. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type
2016-04-22T04:09:58.023056+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:75:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :polymorphic. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: Can you try renaming your join table to be a symbol?  so :user_roles rather than "user_roles"

Comment: Hi I just tried changing it from :join_table = :user_roles to the way it is set out above. It makes no difference to the error message. I'm trying to decipher what the error means? Can you understand the message?

Answer (score 0):

**partial answer**
I just found this:https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/315

If you have 'rolify' in the user model, you don't need to write HABTM Roles

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that in the error message as well.  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1694: warning: already initialized constant User::HABTM_Roles"

Comment: Although this message still appears and i still have application error from heroku: Preloading application
2016-04-22T04:09:58.023038+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ! Unable to load application: ArgumentError: Unknown key: :polymorphic. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type
2016-04-22T04:09:58.023056+00:00 app[web.1]:

Comment: see my other answer.  I commented earlier and deleted it because I thought you solved the problem but it is the :polymoric true  bit that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Unknown key: :polymorphic. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type
```

Makes me think it is from this line:

```
belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
```

as that is the only polymorphic key I see.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: I thought it might be that too, however I commented you the :polymorphic => true bit and tried again, but I still get the same error - so it's not that

Comment: in fact, removing that line entirely still gives the same error